# Remove CSS 'transform' using DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom-manipulation

I need to remove the following from a div's styling using DOM manipulation:

`transform: translateY(-50%)`

The div has the following class name: 'jsx-4186082927'

Please can someone help me with how to remove the transform CSS styling using javascript or jquery?

edit: I have tried
 `window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName("jsx-4186082927")[0].removeAttribute("style", "transform");`

but hasn't work

Comment: Since its "cascading" whats stopping you? Perhaps the element you name doesnt have the style to remove?

Comment: You dont need javascript for this. A css issue

Comment: @GetSet I can't amend the CSS myself as I have no control over it, I have to use javascript to amend it.

Comment: Okay ..... didnt know that. Also didnt know you could inject css. Ok what i mean is CSS itself stands for "cascading style sheet". The "cascading" part means you can override previous rules. In case you didnt realize jessiebower. But sometimes what happens in error, end up targeting the wrong element or class and think its impossible

Comment: @GetSet sorry I am still very new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Remove the transform CSS property from the selected DOM element   
$(".jsx-4186082927").css({ 'transform' : ''});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain JS (not tested):

```js
window.querySelector('.jsx-4186082927').style.transform = undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$('.jsx-4186082927').css('transform','none');
```